# aws-sdk-go describeStacks() trying to get a list of stackids or get stackid from stack name

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk

First I apologice for my English and I advice I'm new to Go.
I'm trying to get a list of all stackId's on my opsworks stacks,
or to give the stackname like I did with the ruby sdk and get the stackid so I can use with another service calls, but for now im trying to get them all to get familiar with the sdk.

```
func main() {

        svc := opsworks.New(session.New(&aws.Config{
                Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
                Credentials: credentials.NewSharedCredentials("", "development"),
        })) 


        resp, err := svc.DescribeStacks()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
                return
        }       

        fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

the reason I omitted "params" is because of this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/opsworks.html#type-DescribeStacksInput
that says: "An array of stack IDs that specify the stacks to be described. If you omit this parameter, DescribeStacks returns a description of every stack."

O keep getting or "not enough arguments in call to svc.DescribeStacks"
or "alidationException: Please provide no arguments or, one or more stack IDs"  or "!v(PANIC=reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value)"

So I'm trying many ways.. not just the one I pasted here.. thats why diff results... changing to () to (nil) etc.. to omit the parameters so I can get a list of all the stacks.
Im sure is very silly, any idea? I have search in google etc but all examples are for ec2 or s3...

Comment: Calling `svc.DescribeStacks(nil)` works for me. Did you set up your credentials correctly?

Comment: seems like it, I have different profiles in my ~/.aws/credentials that's why using it this way.

Comment: this is what I get with (nil) %!v(PANIC=reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value)  why works for you and not for me? nothing in that error tells me anything

Comment: I opened an issue with the sdk.. because when I change the region I get another msg... https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/540

Comment: That's because there is only one endpoint for opsworks. (us-east-1) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#opsworks_region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got a response that worked in the main github issues site.

I see thanks for clarifying. The example you listed in 180498284 is actually the best way to get a list of all of your stack Ids.

To retrieve the individual stack Ids from the response you use the fields of opsworks.DescribeStacksOutput struct. This struct has a field Stacks which is a list of opsworks.Stack structs. The StackId is a field on this struct.

```
resp, err := svc.DescribeStacks(nil)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

for _, stack := range resp.Stacks {
   stackName := aws.StringValue(stack.Name)
   if stackName == owstackname {
       fmt.Printf("found %s stackid\n", stackName)
       fmt.Println(aws.StringValue(stack.StackId))
   }
}
```

The aws.StringValue functions are helpers to convert the string pointer types of the SDK's input/output structs to values. It also protects against the value being nil where it will return empty string.